# React modern calendar datepicker Overlaps with datepicker inputs below

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I am using [react-modern-calendar-datepicke](https://github.com/Kiarash-Z/react-modern-calendar-datepicker) in table. In my application, there is date-picker in every row. When the date picker opens from the bottom it's overlapping the values of the date pickers in the below rows.

**Check my sample in the sandbox**: [Open Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-dream-d9hwo?file=/src/App.js:0-4767)

[image]

But it works fine when the calendar opens from the top.   [image]

I tried to change the z-index but didn't work for me. Does anyone have any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need to change position and z-index on parent element.

Here is simple demo : **(Full code you can check bottom SandBox)**

```
          <td style={{ position:"relative", zIndex:"999" }}>
            <DatePicker
              value={selectedDay}
              onChange={setSelectedDay}
              inputPlaceholder="Select a day"
              shouldHighlightWeekends
            />
          </td>
```

Also I modify your code, hope to help you !

Code Sample for you :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

P.S. this solution which is also I use in my project.

Before fixed :
[image]

After fixed :
[image]

Hope to help you !